# I don't understand variable shell script definition

Tags: sh

I use the one shell script for cleaning some directories.

```
DAYS=${1-10}

echo `date` "INFO Cleaning tmp, log, backup, xml data files older than $DAYS days"
```

What's the meaning of `${1-10}` on variable `DAYS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assigns the value of `$1` to `DAYS`, *unless* `$1` is not set. In that case, a default value of 10 is used.

```
$ echo ${1-10}
10
$ set 5
$ echo ${1-10}
5
```

As an aside, it should probably be `DAYS=${1:-10}`, so that a null value is also replaced with 10. `""` is probably not a useful value for `DAYS`.

Answer (score 1):

`$1` is the first command line argument to your script:

```
$ myscript.sh foo
```

sets `$1` to `foo`. So `DAYS` is `foo`.

`${1-10}` makes `10` the *default value*:

```
$ myscript.sh
```

sets `DAYS` to `10`.